# When using soappy SOAPServer, how do I read the request's headers?

Tags: python, web-services, soap, soappy

I've got a Python webservice using SOAPpy.  The webservice server is structured as shown below:

```
class myClass:
  def hello():
    return 'world'

if __name__ == "__main__":
  server = SOAPServer( ( 'localhost', 8888 ) )
  myObject = myClass()
  namespace = 'whatever::namespace'
  server.registerObject( myObject, namespace )
  server.serve_forever()
```

If a client calls the `hello()` method from my webservice, how can I read the headers, so I can start logging some information (for example: ip address) for debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to do the logging in your hello method?  Here's a minimal example that shows how to pass the SOAPContext information (which can give you some of this info) into the function/method call:

```
from SOAPpy import *

def hello(_SOAPContext = None):
    return "Your IP address is %s" % _SOAPContext.connection.getpeername()[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
  server = SOAPServer( ( '10.3.40.104', 8080 ) )
  server.registerFunction( MethodSig(hello, keywords=0, context=1) )
  server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add a `RequestHandler` to the SoapServer object that extends the `SOAPRequestHandler` and replaces the `HeaderHandler` (have a look at the source of [server.py](http://github.com/btbytes/soappy/blob/master/SOAPpy/Server.py) for an example)